# How to update foreign key to an existing value in one query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have 3 table:

```
A: id, name
B: id, name
AB: id, id_a, id_b
```

Table `AB` links `A` to `B`, with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE CASCADE` for both constraints. Now I find out that in fact the record with id 5 in `B` is duplicated with the record with id 7, both are referenced by table `AB`.

How can I update all record in AB that references `B` 5 to `B` 7? The obvious solution is an `UPDATE` query, but I want a faster way, in case there's more tables referencing `B`

Comment: `update` is how one updates records in SQL.  What could you possibly mean by "a faster way"?

Comment: Are you asking how to find all tables referencing `B.id` to be able to update them too?

Comment: I have to run update for each table, is there any way to do it in one query?